# create oauth2 isn't working

Tags: node.js, meteor, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build a web app on Meteor with Outlook mail API. The first step is to get user authentication through the Outlook mail API, which requires a custom URL with local host, client id, secret, etc attached.

I've looked at a few node.js oauth2 tutorials and downloaded simple-oauth2. All the tutorials use something like:

```
 const oauth2 = require('oauth2').create({
  client: {
     id: '<client-ID>',
     secret: '<app-password>',
  },
  auth: {
     tokenHost: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
     authorizePath: 'common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
     tokenPath: 'common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
  }
});
```

When I run it, the console logs "Uncaught TypeError: require(...).create is not a function." Is create() something that comes with some sort of download that I don't have? The require works fine if I split it up into two parts, so I know it's an issue with create().

Answer (score 0):

First of all wenn you list const then don´t extend them at the end only you know what you do.

Second I don´t use Outlook API but I use OneDrive API and it should be similar. You need to follow the docs about how to get the auth code. Or here my guide for creating it for OneDrive should be same to your problem

Add application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ you need microsoft account for this.

Input your Application Name. In this case, don't use Guided Setup

Create Application secret and copy it to save loaction

Add Platform and choose web. In this case, redirect URL is http://localhost/dashboard

Go to Graph access below and choose for both options Files.ReadWrite.All

Make sure you press save.

Enter your client ID in this url where xxxxxx is. Notice that client ID is the Application ID you can find at the top of your application settings.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&scope=offline_access%20files.readwrite.all&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/dashboard

Please inport above URL to your browser. Log in with your microsoft account and then give your application access by clicking yes. Then you will get redirected to http://localhost/dashboard/?code=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx

This auth code can be used for the access_token that will be generated with this step

```
request.post({url:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', form: {
    redirect_uri: 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf',
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    code: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
}
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ 
console.log('err: ' + err)
console.log('body: ' + body)
});
```

This is basicly the same process for every oAuth2 API. Notice that I use for other API´s in the access_token request the redirect_uri http://localhost/dashboard

If you make a request on and console.log as example the body and you get object object as result then please use stringify. Hope it could help you